# Magento 1.9 free version translation

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, localisation

I would like to ask you about translation Magento. I have translation to Polish but in version 1.9 during registration customer processs there is a text:

What's this?
Checking "Remember Me" will let you access your shopping cart on this computer when you are logged out

I have inline frontend translation turned on but this can't be translated. How can I do it? And where and how to find some text to translation?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/remember_me_tooltip.phtml

In magento 1.7.*

```
....

<div class="remember-me-popup-body">
    <p>Checking &quot;Remember Me&quot; will let you access your shopping cart on this computer when you are logged out</p>
    <div class="remember-me-popup-close-button a-right">
        <a href="#" class="remember-me-popup-close button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Close') ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Close') ?></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since this seem to be an oversight in core magento, you would need to make this change on all site that uses your translation.

```
<p><?php echo $this->__("Checking &quot;Remember Me&quot; will let you access your shopping cart on this computer when you are logged out") ?></p>
```